# How to set date in to QDateEdit from Variable or Text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qdateedit

Below is the example code:

```
date = "1-Jan-2020"
widget_date = QtWidgets.QDateEdit()
widget_date .setDisplayFormat("d-MMM-yyyy")
widget_date .setDate(QDate.fromString(date))
```

I want to set that date  to QtWidgets.QDateEdit().
But it is setting up the default date as 1-jan-2000

Comment: I edited my question please find..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing concepts, `setDisplayFormat()` establishes the format of how the text will be displayed in the widget and nothing intervenes with the conversion of the string to QDate:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    date_str = "1-Jan-2020"
    # convert str to QDate
    qdate = QtCore.QDate.fromString(date_str, "d-MMM-yyyy")

    widget_date = QtWidgets.QDateEdit()
    # Set the format of how the QDate will be displayed in the widget
    widget_date.setDisplayFormat("d-MMM-yyyy")

    widget_date.setDate(qdate)
    
    widget_date.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be possible due to your date is in string format. So can u use `widget_date.setDisplayFormat("%d-%b-%Y")`